# How to store string generated by curl in a variable in a Batch script

Tags: batch-file

I need to store a string generated and associated with a user by a URL in a variable.
I have tried the following:

```
 set /p string
    curl -f -s https://someURL.com/token -d hostname=%USERNAME% > %string%
    echo %string%
```

Comment: `>` only redirects to a file. Either use a temp file, or use [for /f in command output](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html), You could also consider using powershell instead, which has invoke-webrequest builtin and fuly integrated rather than a separate program.

Comment: ```set /p "string="``` is the correct syntax, for retrieving user input and saving it as a variable, not ```set /p string```. There are thousands of examples of batch files on this site which show or explain how to return the result of a command as a variable. Please use the search facility at the top of the page.

Comment: Thanks @compo. Yes, I searched here before posting my question but they did not work when attempting to implement. Do you have a specific one I can attempt?  I think the fact that I associate with a computer name might be an added complexity which is preventing it from working.